# How to Print a File without using a streamreader in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing

I want to print files like doc, html, xml, ...
All examples that I find are using a streamreader. Is there something which prints my file without reading it and saves it in a string?

It's very important for me that it doesn't save the text in a string first because the files have different encodings and formatting.

Comment: If you need to get the text inside you will always need the encoding. But you could create a function to read the first few bytes and determine the encoding

Comment: And if you know the encoding you can use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456(v=vs.110).aspx) of `StreamReader`